# downloaded WAV file will not play

Tags: php, wav, download

I am downloading a WAV file from my remote server (Centos 5.8).  using the following PHP script:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: audio/x-wav');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($realLink));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($realLink));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($realLink);
```

When I try to play the downloaded file using either Windows Media Player or Itunes, it will not play.  Even though the downloaded WAV on my local machine has a file size that is the same as the version of the file on the server, the downloaded file's properties show 00:00 length and will not play.  Also, the file downloads and plays just fine if I manually download it using ftp.  The apparent corruption only happens when I use the above script to download. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: use content type `audio/vnd.wave` or `application/octet-stream`

Comment: tried both of those - audio/vnd.wave and application/octet-stream.  Didn't make any difference.  The original file is x-wav format, so I corrected the code to reflect that.   Still having the same problem though.

Comment: Did you try to `diff` the two files (original and corrupt download) or open them in a hex editor to see the difference?

Comment: @fab Thanks!  That helped.  I looked at the hex files and found the problem.  I am using Zend Framework and it turns out that I still had a view script attached to the controller where this function is implemented. The header function was merging a <div> tag from the view script with the WAV file data.   Saw it in the data as soon as I checked the hex output.  Disabled the view script and it works great now!

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this? Im having trouble but I believe its because of the content disposition. Itunes doesnt like it for some reason

Answer (score 3):

The following are valid MIME types for WAVs:

```
audio/vnd.wave
audio/wav
audio/wave
audio/x-wav
```

You're using `application/x-wav`. See [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2361) and [here](http://filext.com/file-extension/WAV) for references.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change to audio/x-wav and tried audio/wav as well.  Didn't make any difference.  The weird thing is that this script work perfectly when I use it to download an mp3 from the same folder on the remote server(with the proper changes to the Content-Type).  When I look at the downloaded WAV files they are identified as waves in the properties, but the length says 00:00.  On downloaded mp3s everything is as it should be in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for download wav audio.

```
$ctype ='audio/x-wav'; // file type
$filepath = '/var/www/html/audio.wav';//absolute url
$size = filesize($fichero); // size of file
$name = basename($fichero); // name of file

$fp=fopen($fichero, "rb");
if ($size && $ctype && $fp) {
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: wav file");
    header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $name);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-length: " . $size);
    ob_clean();
    fpassthru($fp);
}
```